# Encrypted, password-protected file creation

Tags: file, ms-word, extract, encryption, self-extracting

I'm writing a program that creates a Word document with sensitive information. I'd like to encrypt and password protect the document and distribute it in a self-extracting file so that the user can double-click, provide a password, and then receive the unencrypted file.

I'm okay creating the Word document, but I'd like a third-party program, scriptable or not (I can use the command-line), that can:

1. Encrypt the Word document,
2. Password-Protect the encryption, and
3. Create a self-extracting file.

Can anyone suggest software for this purpose? Anything of SSL security or higher is sufficient since the data was formerly hosted on an SSL-encrypted site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com) does this.    You can script it or program it.  There are command-line tools and a GUI tool to produce ZIPs or self-extracting archives that are AES-encrypted. 
free.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps what you want is simply a [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) that has been encrypted and and setup for self extraction.

Answer (score 2):

[finecrypt.net](http://www.finecrypt.net/) should met your requirements (free version [here](http://www.finecrypt.net/download.html))

[image: Finecrypt]

Answer (score 2):

[WinRAR](http://rarlab.com) can create self-extracting archives with password protection. It uses 128-bit AES for encryption. Self-extractor's window is configurable. You get good compression as a bonus.

Comment: On a tangent: What's the deal with RAR? Why did we need yet another compression utility, why is it so proprietary, and why are warez sites so excited about it?

Comment: Ah yes, kids and their newfangled RAR and ZIP. Everything after ARC and LHA is superfluous.

Seriously though, WinRAR has good compression, quite decent GUI on Windows, and dozens of smaller features, like encryption, sfx installer, splitting with redundant part for recovery.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to encrypt a Word document, dinamically on a LAMP server, exactly as MS Word does, you may use the Crypto API of PHPDocX: [CryptoPHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/cryptophpdocx-word-document-protection-and-encryption-with-php).

Take into account the encrypted MS Word files are MS Compound File Binaries and not standard OOXML/OPC files.

The advantages over other solutions are:

- Office recognizes directly the encrypted files as Word files
- Word prompts you directly to introduce a password
- Whenever the modified Word document is saved it preserves its encrypted status
- Encryption algorithm is AES128

The CryptoPHPDocX API also allows for document protection (not secure but pretty useful to exachange documents that you want to protect from direct edition) and can also encrypt PDF files.